# Point cluster alogrithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

Is there any C# lib available to compute a point cluster(cloud?)?

I got a map with 5-50k points and need to cluster points based on the zoom level - but I also need a way to filter out the points that aren't visible before I compute the clusters.

My idea was to compute all the clusters for N-zoom levels/map scales and split them into a grid. Then the map sends a ajax request saying "I'm at the coordinate, with this extent, and a map scale of" - the server queries the cache for all grid items matching the clients request and the sends the response.

Is this a workable idea, overkill, or just one of those "so far away from how its normal to do it"?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [k-means clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)? Will it be OK as an answer? Or are you looking for a library and not an algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are trying to do here is two things: (1) find the relevant points from a given point given a zoom level, and (2) not include points that are too close together given a zoom level.

If this is the case, then (1) is trivial: you compute the distance to each point from the observation point. Only points under the threshold distance are included. The threshold distance is a function of the zoom level.

To do (2) you want to avoid computing the distance of each point to each other point because that is computationally intensive. What you do is a Delaunay triangulation of the points discovered in step (1). Then, compute the area of each triangle. Then, for each point add up the areas of the triangles for which it is a vertex. Sort the points by this value (the total triangular area--TTA). Remove all points which have a TTA below a zoom-level-dependent threshold. You can discover the best thresholds to use by experimentation.